# How to calculate mean and Variance of Gaussian-distributed random noise?

Tags: matlab, noise, power-spectral-density

I have been given a Gaussian-distributed random noise n(t) which has an average power of 5 mW.
How can I calculate the mean and variance of noise n(t)? Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Please tell us in what form you were "given" the Gaussian-distributed random noise. Don't be shy; tell us _exactly_ what you were "given". Have you been told the power spectral density? Were you told that is _white_ Gaussian noise? _band-limited_ white Gaussian noise? Is it _continuous-time_ noise or _discrete-time_ noise?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Hi! In The question I have only been given that A Gaussian-distributed random noise n(t) has an average power of 5 mW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the values for each sample of $n(t)$ are given, then the mean and variance can be *estimated* using the equations for sample mean and sample variance, which is trivial so I assume the OP is only given that it is Gaussian-distributed with average power of 5 mW. From that alone, there is no way to know what the mean of the signal is since it hasn't been specified that the process is "zero-mean" or not. If the signal does have a mean value, it will contribute to the total power so this must be specified.

The variance **is** the portion of the power that is not included in the mean. Since units of power were provided, then the resistance would need to also be given in order to provide units for any non-zero mean (voltage or current) if there is a mean value.

Comment: How can the mean and variance be _computed_ from sample values? Did you mean _estimated_ as in _sample mean_ and _sample variance_ the way the folks over at stats.SE do it when given $N$ (independent) sample values of an alleged Gaussian random variable?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Consider the mean to be zero, so now how can I calculate the variance? Thanks!

Comment: @Pressing_Keys_24_7 See my second paragraph and let me know what is still confusing you about that sentence. You have zero mean, so mean is zero. Therefore all the power is the variance.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot for the help!